# SQL Server LIKE query speed in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am doing a LIKE query to count the number of matching records within a table of 10+ million records. When I run the query as a standalone query it returns a result within 6 seconds on average. When I set the query to run on a number of records within a stored procedure, the process takes approx 10 times longer than an individual query.

The single query:

```
select COUNT(*) as NumCount
from dataTable
where textField like '%%' + @test + '%%';
```

in trying to do it in bulk I am reading the processing list into a temporary table and then running them as:

```
update #t
    set fieldCount = (select COUNT(*) as NumCount
                      from dataTable
                      where textField like '%%' + dataField + '%%'
                     );
```

I have tried various options but all run slower when trying to process in bulk compared to running a single query, and I need to process 1000s on a daily basis.
Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: You may find that full text indexes are the only way to accomplish this.  And why do you use `%%`?  That should be the same as `%`.

Comment: One possibility is that with a constant (`@test`), SQL Server can "pre-compile" the `like` pattern.  With a column, it has to re-evaluate it on every row.  The difference in performance surprises me, so perhaps there is another explanation.

Comment: How many records are in table #t? Are you sure it is not the updating that is taking time?

Comment: Can you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` for the query in the stored procedure and see whether it makes any difference?

Comment: This sounds like parameter sniffing (https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/parameter-sniffing/). Can you compare the execution plan from the single query vs the stored procedure?

Comment: I have tried full text indexing, but because I am searching for matches within strings, i.e. 'tennis' within 'lawntennisclub' that does not work.

Comment: Ideally I would want to populate the temp table #t with 1000 records but even running it with 5 or ten, it is slow. I have also tried it simply returning a result without doing an update, also just as slow. 

I will try the OPTION (RECOMPILE), and look at parameter sniffing. I did run it with STATISTICS IO on and didn't see any particular differences in execution.